# Mac mini doesn't boot into Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, recovery

Model # shows as Macmini8,1 and Ventura 13.2. Directly connected the USB keyboard to the Mini.

I shut down the Mac and held <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> down and restarted the Mini and held it until the Apple logo; it boots straight into the OS.

The Mini used to have an older OS installed but now it's Ventura formatted as APFS.

How can I get to Recovery Mode; I'm trying to clone my drive.

Here's my `diskutil` list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     163.6 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.4 GB     disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            12.8 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 12.8 GB    disk1s5s1
```

There seems to be a recovery partition.

Comment: `Cmd-Opt-R` *is* Internet recovery.  Two things to check:  a) is the keyboard fully functional and b) try changing the USB port the keyboard is plugged into.  Make sure it’s direct to mini an not going through a hub.  If it’s in the first port, plug it into the second.

Comment: I don't know in practice how much difference this would make, but you're supposed to press your key combo when you hear the chimes, not before power on. [Can't test right now, things running I can't close.]

Comment: I tried both Cmd+R and Cmd+Opt+R - boots to the login screen. Also I waited till the chime and then pressed key - I see the Apple logo quickly after the chime and again at the login screen. I enabled the Accessibility keyboard and comfirmed that the os was getting Cmd+R when I pressed it and it hilights both keys. It's not a Apple keyboard though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a non-Apple keyboard.

The problem was, that I had re-mapped the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Win</kbd> keys within macOS to Mac key config.

When I was rebooting, of course, those mappings were not in place.

So when I thought I was typing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, I was actually typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Duh.

The correct key for Windows keyboards is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!  We become used to the fact that a super huge majority of folks here use MacBooks so we don’t ask about keyboards.  I’ll try to keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Sure - especially if they say mac mini (as opposed to a mac laptop) because they can hook any keyboard to it.